# RPC Batch call abruptly stopped working

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-core-development, full-node

I've had this code that was working less than a week ago. No changes at all on my PC or in the code and it just abruptly stopped working

normal (single) RPC calls work fine but batch does not.

All firewalls are off, no virus protection so can rule those out. Nothing changed w/ port forwarding and I see both inbound/outbound traffic on my node. I've restarted the PC, restarted bitcoin core (as admin too)

```
commands = [["getblockhash", height] for height in range(0, 100000)]
            block_hashes = rpc_connection.batch_(commands)
```

I don't understand why the single RPC calls are working fine but the batch is not

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some very painful debugging, I've figured out the problem. I don't quite understand why but I've resolved it for now.

**There's an upper limit to the number of rpc batch requests you can make through AuthProxy.batch_(). The exact number (at least for getblockhash) is 420819.** What the significance of this number is, I'm not really sure. Maybe it's a bitcoinlib issue, maybe it's a bitcoin core issue, it might be a networking sockets issue.

I'll figure out the root cause eventually but I'll have to rewrite my code to get around this limitation.